# How can i run qt c++ console application in invisible mode?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I made simple qt c++ application in Q creator. it is working fine.  if the console window close,the program will terminate. I want to run this application even 
if the console window closes.How can i achieve this? 
How can i run qt c++ console application in invisible mode?

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your .pro file in a text editor like Gedit or nano.

Then find this line:
CONFIG += CONSOLE

delete this line, save it, recompile